# jQuery: search for next checkbox and disable it

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a few `checkbox` elements and I want to disable the next (or previous).

My code looks like this:

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkOk" />
</td>

<td>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkNotOk" />
</td>

<!-- Futher checkboxes -->
```

I tried:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').bind("click", function () {
        $(this).next('input[type=checkbox]').attr("disabled");
    });
});
```

And also:

```
$(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').attr("disabled");
```

But it does not work. Please help.

Comment: The way you're using `attr` there is the *getter* rather than the *setter*; have you tried using `.attr("disabled", true);`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to go up to the parent `td` and find the next checkbox from there:

```
var n = $(this).parent().nextAll().has(":checkbox").first().find(":checkbox");
```

This gets the `td` using [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), then gets all the following siblings ([`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)) of that `td`, reduces the matched set to only those `td` elements which contain a checkbox ([`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)) and then gets the first one ([`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)) in the remaining set.

Note that `disabled` is a property, and you should be using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set it, not `attr`:

```
n.prop("disabled", true);
```

The problem you were having is because you are looking for siblings of the clicked checkbox, and in your example HTML they don't have any siblings.